# Custom Dictionary read-only property

Tags: c#, dictionary

I created a custom dictionary to implement the `IDataErrorInfo` interface on it, but when I try to set a value to an instance of this Dictionary:

Custom Dictionary:

```
public class MyDictionary<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>, IDataErrorInfo
{

    public string Error
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }



    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
}
```

Then:

```
MyDictionary<string, string> myDict = new MyDictionary<string, string>();
    Dictionary["key"] = "value";
```

I get the following error:

> Property or indexer 'MyDictionary.this[string]' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

I guess I'm missing some kind of Getter/Setter. But shouldn't this be inherited from base class Dictionary? How can I create it?

Comment: a [mcve] would be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is, that `IDataErrorInfo` implements the `this[string]` indexer too.

```
public string this[string columnName]
{
    get { ...; }
}
```

If you want to access the indexer of `Dictionary` you need to cast your variable to `Dictionary` (one of the problems of inheritance)

```
((Dictionary<string,string>)variableName)["key"] = "something";
```

or even better (since you'll probably never use `IDataErrorInfo` manually), implement the interface **explicitly**:

```
string IDataErrorInfo.this[string columnName]
{
    get { return ...; }
}
```

That way you can use the `Dictionary` like usual and the `IDataErrorInfo` indexer by casting

```
dictionaryVariable["key"] = "something";
string error = ((IDataErrorInfo)dictionaryVariable)["key"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary has a method called **Add** which you should use to add to the dictionary. You can also use .Contains to ensure the key isn't already used in the dictionary.

Comment: But since I'm extending from the class "Dictionary" that already has this method implemented, shouldn't my custom class inherit it?

Comment: Yes. i misread the question. Manfred Radlwimmer has the correct answer.